# linux command line: find a host's canonical hostname

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bash, hostname

what is the easiest way to get a host's canonical host name from linux's command line?

If it matters, my shell is bash.

**CLARIFICATION:** I want another host's canonical hostname, either by ip or by non canonical hostname. Not the local host's canonical hostname.

Answer (score 11):

Use `dig(1)`. For normal lookups use:

```
dig full.hostname.xxx
```

and for reverse lookups use:

```
dig -x 127.0.0.1
```

Also check the man page for much more cool options.

Answer (score 6):

A remote host's node name bears no necessary relationship to any of its network names.  You'll have to log in and use the `hostname` command.

If you're looking for the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of a network address, you can use DNS query tools like `dig` or `nslookup`, as described by @firm and @Richard Holloway.

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, `hostname` will just return the short name.   Use the `-f` parameter; `hostname -f` to get the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 3):

You could use also the **host** command. Like in this example

```
host xxx.xxx.xxx.xyz
```

The result will be something like

```
xyz.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer name.domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the fqdn of a remote host with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx you can use

```
nslookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

and see the answer contains

```
name = host.domain.net
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "reverse lookup" for canonical names. That is: given an A record, there is no way to get a listing of what CNAME records point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command:

`hostname`

Comment: I want another host's canonical hostname, either by ip or by non canonical hostname. I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the IP address by name, and then look up the name for that IP address. To do that in one command:

```
$ dig -x `dig +short www.google.com` | grep PTR.
 100.212.58.216.in-addr.arpa. 86309 IN  PTR lhr35s06-in-f4.1e100.net.
 100.212.58.216.in-addr.arpa. 86309 IN  PTR lhr35s06-in-f100.1e100.net.
```

This doesn't work for all sites.